# C++ Dereferencing pointer to object

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm having some trouble dereferencing a pointer.

```
priority_queue<node*, vector< node*>, comparator>* pQueue = NULL;

pQueue = h->addToQueue(m);


while (!pQueue->empty())
{

    cout << (*pQueue)->top() << endl;

    pQueue->pop();


}
```

`addQueue(m)` returns a pointer to a priority queue, but when I try to print it I'm only getting memory address values.

Any ideas why?

Thanks..

Comment: `node` is an object type I've created

Comment: `pQueue->top()` is a `node *`. Of course it's going to print an address.

Comment: You have a queue of pointers to node objects. `pQueue->top()` gives you such a pointer and printing it will correctly give a memory address.

Comment: Have you defined a print method for priority queue objects? Otherwise, <<  is going to know nothing other than that it's a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to overload the `<<` operator for your node class like:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const node& nd)
{
    os << nd.anyvalue;
    return os;
}
```

also you have to dereference your pointer like

```
cout << *pQueue->top()<< endl;
```

look at the example here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/1z2f6c2k.aspx

or here:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/input_output_operators_overloading.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try something like `cout << *pQueue->top() << endl;`

Comment: That doesn't work either. Using the while loop prints the values fine when I haven't allocated things dynamically.

Comment: If `top()` returns `node*`, so `*pQueue->top()` can't print address. See Martin Schlott answer  with operator overload. May be it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`pQueue->top()` returns a `node*`, which is an address to a `node`.
So naturally if you try to print it directly you will end up printing an address.